# Failed to install Microsoft Analysis Sevrices Projects extension vs2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I downloaded  [Microsoft Analysis Sevrices Projects extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zIGy.png) via Extensions and Updates inside Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and tried to install it.
but when download finished, VSIX gave me this error:

10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - -------------------------------------------
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - 16.9.1050
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - -------------------------------------------
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - Command line parameters:
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Enterprise,/skuVersion:15.0.27004.2002,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017,/culture:en-US,C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXgvrnn1ly.vsix
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - -------------------------------------------
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - -------------------------------------------
10/05/2021 06:53:07 PM - Initializing Install...
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM - Extension Details...
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    Identifier         : 04a86fc2-dbd5-4222-848e-911638e487fe
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    Name               : Microsoft Analysis Services Projects
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    Author             : Microsoft
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    Version            : 2.9.17
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    Description        : Microsoft Analysis Services projects provide project templates and design surfaces for building professional data models hosted in SQL Server Analysis Services on-premises, Microsoft Azure Analysis Services, and Microsoft Power BI.
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    Locale             : en-US
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    MoreInfoURL        :
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    InstalledByMSI     : False
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
10/05/2021 06:53:08 PM -
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -    SignatureState     : ValidSignature
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -    SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -    Certificate Info   :
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        -------------------------------------------------------
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        [Serial Number] : 33000003C93EFB7FE21A3D22B30000000003C9
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        [Not Before]    : 15/12/2020 11:24:05 PM
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        [Not After]     : 02/12/2021 11:24:05 PM
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        [Thumbprint]    : E120FF932F2D4DFB59B1DA16BA7C397119E2DEBF
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -    Supported Products :
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -            Version : [15.0.28010,17.0)
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -    References         :
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        -------------------------------------------------------
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        Identifier   : BAB64743-DA65-4501-B3A3-A73171C73D77
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        Name         : Microsoft BI Shared Components for Visual Studio
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        Version      : [5.0.0,6.99)
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        MoreInfoURL  :
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        Nested       : Yes
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -    Prerequisites      :
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        -------------------------------------------------------
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        Identifier   : Microsoft.Net.Component.4.TargetingPack
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        Name         : .NET Framework 4 targeting pack
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -        Version      : [15.0,17.0)
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM - Signature Details...
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -    Extension is signed with a valid signature.
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM -
10/05/2021 06:53:34 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData) at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

Help Me please

Answer (score 0):

I had also a problem with that SSAS extension version, but in my case root cause was different, it mainly complained that a particular .dll already existed.

According to your log "06:53:34 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products. at", is there any update available for your Visual Studio? I would try first update Visual Studio and then update SSAS Extension.

I had two servers, in one of them SSAS update worked fine, but on the other not. On server where it worked fine I did an Visual Studio update before SSAS extension one. On the other one I had to rename certain folders (softer than remove them) to get rid of the "already exists problems".

See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b22ef99f-7d3d-4520-8132-bdd7571c1ced/visual-studio-2019-analysis-services-project-extension-vsix-295-not-working?forum=vssetup

Kind regards,